# Server returned error NXDOMAIN on Ubuntu EC2 instance for domain

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I'm struggling with a quite weird issue. I have a working EC2 instance and trying to connect it with my domain in Route 53.

After changing `nginx` configuration to the domain it's just not working.

I have found some logs via `sudo nano /var/log/syslog` and I see something interesting:

> Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation
>   DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.

Could you explain me what is the point of this error?

Here is my part of my `nginx` config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name mydomain.dev www.mydomain.dev;
  return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;

  root /home/ubuntu/mydomainfolder_dev/;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
  }
}
```

And here is a proper security group settings connected with EC2 instance:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4581/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1608/systemd-resolv
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      935/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4581/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      935/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      2486/node /home/ubu
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is something related to the limits of my AWS EC2 instance, some script was soooooo consuming.

[AWS EC2 screenshot usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2c9Z.png)